# Unknown status icon that looks like a broken "N"

Tags: notification-icons

There is an unknown status icon that looks like a broken "N" on my LG G4.

[image]

What is it?

Answer (score 5):

The icon is for the [NFC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communicationq), short for Near Field Communication, a feature that helps you use tap-and-go services such as Apple pay, Google Wallet, Amiibo and so.

**Switch NFC on or off:**

From the Home screen, touch and slide the notification panel down with your finger, then select the NFC icon (N) to turn it on or off.